# How to specify the font in an endnote?

Tags: latex

The question is about formatting the endnote font in both 'report' and 'memoir' document classes when using the pagenote package.

In the following minimal example the \footnotesize{} command is obeyed as expected when \footnote is used: the footnote is in 16pt as requested.  When the endnote is used with \pagenote the endnotes appear as expected in both memoir and report environments, but in both cases the main text font is used.

In effect, the question is how to create something like \endnotesize{}?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{memoir}

% set the font size in the footnotes
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}

\let\footnote\pagenote  % toggle endnotes instead of footnotes

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
Here is the main text of the article\footnote{The first footnote in 16pt}
To clarify the situation a second footnote helps\footnote{The second footnote also 16pts}

%\printnotes            % needed for report style
\printpagenotes         % needed for memoir style

\end{document}
```

In this example 'memoir' can be replaced by 'report' if \printnotes is used instead of '\printpagenotes'.  footnotes appear instead of endnotes by commenting out the line '\let\footnote\pagenote'.  In \footnote mode this example provides 16pt footnotes.

My working environment is pdfLatex in TexWorks.

Comment: You may get more responses if you post it on https://tex.stackexchange.com/, the LaTeX Stack Exchange.

Comment: Curiously, most issues I Google about Latex issues have answers on Stack Exchange.  I have accepted samcarter's easy answer (below) so I don't think there is much point in shifting this over to tex.stackexchange.com/.  Which is what I would have done had not samcarter's answer come back so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `memoir` class you can redefine the `\prenotetext` and `\postnotetext` macros like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{memoir}

% set the font size in the footnotes
\makeatother
\renewcommand\prenotetext{\begingroup\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\postnotetext{\endgroup}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}

\let\footnote\pagenote  % toggle endnotes instead of footnotes

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
Here is the main text of the article\footnote{The first footnote in 16pt}
To clarify the situation a second footnote helps\footnote{The second footnote also 16pts}

%\printnotes            % needed for report style
\printpagenotes         % needed for memoir style

\end{document}
```

And for `report` class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{report}

% set the font size in the footnotes
\makeatother


\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}

   
\renewcommand{\prenoteinnotes}{\par\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\noindent}
\renewcommand{\postnoteinnotes}{\par}


\let\footnote\pagenote  % toggle endnotes instead of footnotes

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
Here is the main text of the article\footnote{The first footnote in 16pt}
To clarify the situation a second footnote helps\footnote{The second footnote also 16pts}

\printnotes            % needed for report style
%\printpagenotes         % needed for memoir style

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - impressive speedy answer.  I had scoured the Latex docs for report and memoir styles but I never thought to look for \prenotetext and \postnotetext.  According to my publisher endnotes are the way to go for non-page-oriented documents (as in epub etc.), so perhaps others may benefit from this answer.

Comment: Addendum: I've been using @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz suggestion for some time and it works well for writing smaller documents.  However a large document (400 pages, 20 chapters, 20 footnotes/endnotes per chapter)  causes PDFlatex to come up with the infamous [grouping levels=255] error message when generating  endnotes.  (There is no problem  in footnote-mode.)   The only solution I found was to change the compiler to LuaLaTeX, (which handles memory caching differently). LuaLaTeX requires 3 or more passes to resolve all cross references.  It also works smoothly with hyperref.